# Creating multivariate Q-Q Plots in R

Tags: r

I wish to test for multivariate and univariate normality with Q-Q plots in R. I have used several different methods - they all do not seem to work. I am new to R, and would be incredibly grateful for any help.

My data set = vdata_clean1

I have 15 predicting variables (IV's), but no response variable (DV) because I am running a Confirmatory Factor Analysis (the 15 variables represent 15 different types of items that make up the scale I am testing).

I have installed the following packages:

```
install.packages("lavaan", dependencies=TRUE)
install.packages ("semPlot")
install.packages ("semTools")
install.packages("psych")
install.packages("MVN")
install.packages("mvtnorm")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("qgraph")
install.packages("psych")
```

1. First, I used the mvn function (multivariate q-q plot)

   ```
   mvn(data = vdata_clean1, subset = NULL, mvnTest = c("mardia"),
   covariance = TRUE, tol = 1e-25, alpha = 0.5, scale = FALSE, desc                    
   = TRUE, transform = "none", R = 1000, univariateTest = c("SW"),   
   univariatePlot = "none", multivariatePlot = "q-q",   
   multivariateOutlierMethod = "none", bc = FALSE, bcType = 
   "rounded", showOutliers = FALSE, showNewData = FALSE)
   ```

   => I receive no error messages but the plots do not show.

-

2. Second, I tried the qqnorm function (multivariate q-q plot)

   ```
   qqnorm(vdata_clean1, ylim, main = "Normal Q-Q Plot", xlab = 
   "Theoretical Quantiles", ylab = "Sample Quantiles", plot.it =   
   TRUE, datax = FALSE)
   ```

   => I receive the following error message and no plots:

   ```
   Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.   
   Call `rlang:last_error()` to see a backtrace'
   ```

-

3. I tried the ggplot function for one variable (ILproto_1) (univariate q-q plot)

   ```
   ggplot(vdata_clean1, aes(sample = ILproto_1)) + stat_qq() + 
   stat_qq_line() + labs(title= "Normality Q-Q Plot (ILproto_1)", y 
   = "Sample Quantiles") + theme_classic() `
   ```

   => I received this error message:

   ```
   Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type    
   haven_labelled. Defaulting to continuous.
   Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type   
   haven_labelled. Defaulting to continuous.
   Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x,     
   x$y,  : 
   polygon edge not found
   In addition: Warning message:
   In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,     
   : no font could be found for family "Arial"
   ```

     -
4. I also tried a histogram with the ggplot function (for variable ILproto_1)

   ```
   ggp1 <- ggplot(vdata_clean1, aes(x = ILproto_1))
   ggp1 <- ggp1 + geom_histogram(binwidth=1, colour="black", 
                     aes(y=..density.., fill=..count..))
   ggp1 <- ggp1 + scale_fill_gradient("Count", low="#DCDCDC", 
   high="#7C7C7C")
   ggp1 <- ggp1 + stat_function(fun=dnorm,
                    color="red",
                    args=list(mean=mean(vdata_clean1$ILproto_1), 
                              sd=sd(vdata_clean1$ILproto_1)))
   ggp1
   ```

=> There is no error message, but I receive no plot

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult without a reproducible example. Still, this uses the `mtcars` dataset to create a dataframe with 11 variables with different variables using `ggplot2`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars%>%
  gather()%>%
  ggplot(., aes(sample = value)) +
  stat_qq()+
  facet_wrap(vars(key), scales ='free_y')
```

[image: ggplot2 qqplot facet]

Comment: Thank you for the info - I've tried to create a reproducible example from my data set, but struggle doing so or find any guidelines online. Any ideas on this?

Comment: You can look at some of the datasets built into R. It might be helpful to provide a picture of what you want a graph to look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the [mqqnorm](https://rdrr.io/cran/RVAideMemoire/man/mqqnorm.html) function from the {RVAideMemoire} package.

It creates a multivariate QQplot based on squared generalized distances and uses
chi-square as theoretical distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Univariate QQ plots are often too confusing when you have a collection of variables as in the `mtcars` data.

For multivariate data, what you really want is a chisq-QQplot of Mahalanobis squared distances. When the data is NVN, this should follow a $\chi^2$ distribution with p degrees of freedom for p variables.

The function [heplots::cqplot](http://friendly.github.io/heplots/reference/cqplot.html) does this plot for you. It also offers point identification by a criterion and a detrended version.

```
heplots::cqplot(mtcars, id.n = 2)
```

[image]

```
heplots::cqplot(mtcars, id.n = 2, detrend = TRUE)
```

[image]